# Enrollment issue with a Wishtel device

Tags: android-management-api

We cannot enrol a Wishtel IRA Tablet device in device owner mode using the Android Management API. The enrollment process stops before launching our companion app during setup (through the `setupActions` profile setting).

The enrollment process is detailed below:

1. Tap 7 times on the welcome screen
2. Configure the WiFi network
3. Checking for updates
4. Installing QR reader
5. Flash the QR code
6. Set up your device screen
7. Setting up work device screen
8. Just a sec... screen
9. Android home screen is displayed

The device information is:

- Model & hardware: `IRAI1705`
- Android version: `8.1.0`
- Android security patch level: `5 September 2018`
- Build number: `Wishtel_IRA_20181018`

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: Thanks for reporting Florian. It may be an issue with this specific brand of devices, we're looking into it.

Comment: I'll submit a full bug report soon, just need our customer to create it, since we don't have the device at hand. I'll let you know when it's ready.